# Laravel 5 POST method is not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

### My Laravel get method is working but post method is not working.

### controller

```
public function create(Request $request)
{

    if (Request::isMethod('post'))
    {
        echo 'text';
        exit;
    }

}
```

### blade

```
<form action="{{route('create')}}" method="POST">
<input name="name" class="form-control" type="text">    
<input name="email" class="form-control" type="email">  
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" name="submit">
</form>
```

### route

```
Route::post('/create', 'Tools\PostController@create')->name('create');
```

### error

***The page has expired due to inactivity. 
Please refresh and try again.***

Comment: are you sure that static isMethod call is legal? and behaves like expected? i'm pretty sure you're supposed to call it dynamically from $request

Comment: Can you provide more code , with namespaces, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting "The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again" because you are not passing csrf token with the post request.

By default laravel reject any post request without the csfr token in the request.

Try this:

In your blade file include one hidden input like this :

```
<input name="token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

For more info please refer to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf)